# Provide readable error message for errors in ListGrids DataSource

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

I have a ListGrid that uses DataSource. Using the **[documentation](https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/data/DataSource.html#transformRequest-com.smartgwt.client.data.DSRequest-)**. I provided my own implementation for loading the data source data:

```
protected Object transformRequest(DSRequest dsRequest) {  
    // My custom class that loads the data
    this.dataLoader.startLoading(this.getID(), new AsyncCallbackTableData() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            final DSResponse response = new DSResponse(
                    "",
                    DSOperationType.FETCH
            );
            // As per docs, -1 is correct error status
            response.setStatus(-1);

            errors.put("ERROR", caught.getMessage());

            response.setErrors(errors);
            // Process response, as per docs
            MyDataSource.this.processResponse(
                    dsRequest.getRequestId(), 
                    response
            );
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<Record> result) {
            /// stripped for brevity
        }
    });
    return new Object();
}
```

Now what you see above is callback to my data loading code. When the data loads, I provide data to `MyDataSource.this.processResponse` and it works well. However, in the error branch of the callback, I don't know how to pass error message to the user. It understands the `response.setStatus(-1)` as an error, but there is no field for error message.

[image]

How do I specify an error message in `DSResponse`?

Comment: fetchData has callback function where you can check DSResponse. https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/data/DataSource.html#fetchData-com.smartgwt.client.data.Criteria-com.smartgwt.client.data.DSCallback-com.smartgwt.client.data.DSRequest-